# Lottie widget not animating because parent is a stateful widget

Tags: flutter, lottie

I have an app with a Stateful Widget which contains an `AnimatedContainer()` which has another Stateful widget as it's child but it's basically just a wiget that has the `Lottie.asset()` widget as it's child along with it's controller. There's also another problem where the `Lottie.asset()` widget flashes but I think that's because it is rebuilding over and over. I think I need to prevent the Lottie Animation from rebuilding but I'm not sure how to do so.

Here is my Lottie animation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/193ZDqagSDg_U2m6OlZDTj3mY8RtKLcpR/view?usp=sharing

Here's what it looks like in the app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PcGS8h3ab6fIvMqemByZ5STTCa72w4Bi/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, it just cuts and doesn't animate, how can I fix this?

Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/HadyMash/d038c2b41957a6e61126eb5f75cb6354

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by completely eliminating the `Check()` widget as it was easier to control it from the `Todo()`. To fix the flickering I gave it a `GlobalKey()`. Then I just added a controller to `Todo()` and made it go `forward()` or `reverse()` accordingly.

The final result looks something like this: https://cln.sh/EqRyRc